# Outer Join advice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, outer-join

I am a learning SQL Server Using the AdventureWorks Dw 2012, how would I  List reseller name for resellers who have not sold any bikes. Should be 114 Rows

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Hmmm, you haven't written a query.  That would seem necessary to answer this question using the database.

Comment: Show your table definitions and tell us for each table when a row goes into it in terms of its columns. How do we tell you where you are going wrong if you don't show your tables and query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get correct answer to this question, you should provide sample data.

Imagine that we have 2 tables:

`Resellers` where stored information about resellers

`SoldBikes` where stored information about bikes

You have to use `NOT EXISTS` to check If that reseller exists in `SoldBikes` table in following:

```
SELECT [Resseller Name]
FROM Resellers r1    
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM Resellers r2
                   JOIN SoldBikes sb ON r2.id = sb.reseller_id
                   WHERE r1.id = r2.id
                 )
```